# Determine if a number is prime. If not, print the factors of the number

Tags: r

I wrote an R function that checks if a number x is a prime number. If not, then print the factors of that number. In the code, everything seems okay except when to print the factors of a number that is not prime. I have tried many tricks, but it is not working. I need help.

```
prime = function(x){
   if(x>1){
      for(i in 2:(x/2+1)){
         if(x%%i==0){
            print(paste(x,"is not a prime number"))
            print(paste("The factors of",x,"are:"))
            for (j in 1:(x+1)){
               if(x%%j==0){
                  print(paste(j,""))
               break
               }
            }
         }else{
            print(paste(x, "is a prime number"))
            break
         }
      }   
   }else{
      print(paste("Enter value is that is greater than 1"))
   }
}
```

when I called the function, it gives the output below

```
> prime(0)
[1] "Enter value is that is greater than 1"
> prime(19)
[1] "19 is a prime number"
> prime(4)
[1] "4 is not a prime number"
[1] "The factors of 4 are:"
[1] "1 "
[1] "4 is a prime number"
```

Everything worked fine, but I was unable to print the factors of x that is not prime.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you can find much more information _instantly_ by doing a more targeted search. For instance, StackOverflow [`[r] prime factors`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+prime%20factors) by itself is rather featureful, and even Google [`"r" "prime" "factor"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22r%22+%22prime%22+%22factor%22) has some other good blogs/posts/Q&As about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

- Since you want to return all factors of the number when you report that it is not a prime, you shouldn't be `print`ing from inside the `for` loop;
- Your inner loop to find other factors should *not* start at 1, since that's always going to be a factor; ideally it should start at `i+1`, since you already know that `2:(i-1)` are *not* factors.
- Again, inside the `for` loop you should never be reporting that it "is a prime number", since ... you aren't done with the `for` loop yet and therefore don't know if you've exhausted your full list of possible factors. This check (and print) should be after the `for` loop is complete.

---

I suggest using vectorized operations instead of `for` loops.

```r
isprime <- function(x) {
  stopifnot("Value must be greater than 1" = x > 1)
  nums <- seq_len(ceiling(x / 2))
  factors <- setdiff(nums[x %% nums == 0], c(1, x))
  if (length(factors)) {
    message(x, " is not a prime, factors are: ", toString(factors))
  } else message(x, " is a prime")
  invisible(!length(factors) > 0)
}
```

Demo:

```r
isprime(1)
# Error in isprime(1) : Value must be greater than 1
isprime(7)
# 7 is a prime
isprime(60)
# 60 is not a prime, factors are: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30
```

---

If you *must* use a `for` loop, and you need to report all factors  of the number, then I suggest appending known factors to a vector, and check its length outside of the `for` loop for reporting.

```r
isprime_for <- function(x) {
  factors <- integer(0)
  if (x > 1) {
    for (i in 2:floor(x / 2)) {
      if (x %% i == 0) factors <- c(factors, i)
    }
  } else stop("value must be greater than 1")
  if (length(factors) > 0) {
    message(x, " is not a prime, factors are: ", toString(factors))
  } else {
    message(x, " is a prime")
  }
  length(factors) == 0L
}
```

Demo

```r
isprime_for(1)
# Error in isprime_for(1) : value must be greater than 1
isprime_for(7)
# 7 is a prime
# [1] TRUE
isprime_for(20)
# 20 is not a prime, factors are: 2, 4, 5, 10
# [1] FALSE
```